# Excel Vlookup too Slow

Tags: sql, excel, vlookup

I have an Excel file that uses a `vlookup` on around 10000 rows, 8 `Vlookups` per row. Its ridiculously slow.

It looks up another excel file located online -

```
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(E12,'Filepath.xlsx]Data'!$U:BV,54,0)),"None",VLOOKUP(E12,Filepath.xlsx]Data'!$U:BV,54,0))
```

I've looked around and vlookups seem to be pretty necessary. Are there possible structural changes which could make this go faster, such as vlookups on an SQL database?

Thanks

Comment: Try switching to an Index/Match combination. That will allow you to do just one match per row. Also, look at: http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2014/11/17/cult-of-the-flying-spaghetti-vlookup/

Comment: Thanks guys, however I'm looking for something WAY quicker, by about 50% minimum. I work on something that's supposed to be a computer, called a VDI, which is the size of a router.Its always slow with Excel, but since this update its gone ridiculous. I am assuming that no Excel formulas could give this type of increase, so think that I may have to change data format first or something? Not a developer.

Comment: Can you sort column U in `ascending order`? If so you can use a `LOOKUP` formula which will be vastly quicker, should be much more than 50% i.e. `=IFERROR(IF(LOOKUP(E12,Filepath.xlsx]Data'!$U2:$U10000)<>E12,"None",LOOKUP(E12,Filepath.xlsx]Data'!$U2:$BV10000)),"None")`

Comment: Yes, unfortunately this vlookup is done on many columns, and not all can be sorted ascending. So I could  sort ascending in column U, but then v would not be sorted and the associated vlookup would still be slow.

Comment: And god only knows why it's as slow deleting one row as it is 500.

Comment: It's slow deleting one row (or 500 rows) because that changes the `VLOOKUP` ranges and each has to be recalculated.

Comment: Use named ranges also , it really speeds up heavy sheets , but yes INDEX/MATCH is better and easier to manage once setup

Comment: And of course, applying a filter does the same to the Vlookups, judging by how slow its loading?

I could learn index match, with the named range, would this yield significant performance increases(Twice as fast)?

Comment: once you have done the lookups cant you copy and paste special the sheet? so its just data?

Comment: Re sorting: The sort only needs to be on the "lookup range" (the first column of the lookup array) although, of course, the other columns need to be included . Are you saying that the lookup range changes? Using LOOKUP which uses "binary search" means that LOOKUP needs to assess approx 13 (=Log(10000,2) values as opposed to up to 10,000 with VLOOKUP, hence the performance improvement

Comment: I posted an answer which demonstrates the significant speed advantages of LOOKUP with a sorted range over VLOOKUP - Of course it sounds like you might have other factors which affect the speed

Comment: Not to be peevish, well okay, maybe to be peevish, but did you try the Index/Match suggestion with a single Match for each row? Since the match is the part that takes the bulk of the time, it seems like the potential to cut it by 7/8 might be of interest. And it certainly falls within my concept of a "structural change."

Answer (score 3):

As per my comments, using a `LOOKUP` formula with a sorted lookup range is significantly faster than using `VLOOKUP`, **more than 100 times faster** in this case, e.g. doing some speed tests if I use this formula

`=VLOOKUP(B3, $D$3:$D$10002, 1,0)`

and then with G3:G10002 containing the same values as D3:D10002 but sorted ascending this `LOOKUP` formula

`=IF(LOOKUP(B3, $G$3:$G$10002) = B3, LOOKUP(B3, $G$3:$G$10002), NA())`

the formulas produce exactly the same results but the 2nd formula is consistently **120-140** times faster than the first because of the benefits of "binary search"

If I use the `INDEX/MATCH` equivalent, i.e.

`=INDEX($D$3:$D$10002,MATCH(B3, $D$3:$D$10002,0))`

then that's actually marginally slower than the VLOOKUP version, although, as Doug says, if you are using the same `MATCH` formula in multiple calculations then you can calculate that once only for multiple results so that may be more efficient than VLOOKUP over all

Of course there may be other factors in your setup which are slowing down the calculations.....